# How to add/sum total amounts in a column and search it based on date using php?

Tags: php, mysql, search, sum

I'm going to add total amount (**rialamount**) in one column based on (**id_patient**) which is unique for each user and show it on page as Total Amount, and then admin will be able to search From Date, To Date based on (**opening_date**) to see total amount in date Duration.

Here's my sample mysql db:

```
id_patient opening_date rialamount
         1   2015-11-07   250000.00    
         1   2015-11-09    25000.00
         1   2015-11-09   795864.15
         1   2015-11-09 12598755.00
```

and here is sample of what I'm looking for it.

```
<label for="fromdate">From Date:</label>
<input size="4" id="fromdate" name="fromdate" value="" maxlength="4" type="text">
 - <input size="2" id="dmonth" name="dmonth" value="" maxlength="2" type="text">
 - <input size="2" id="dday" name="dday" value="" maxlength="2" type="text">

<label for="todate">To Date:</label>
<input size="4" id="todate" name="todate" value="" maxlength="4" type="text">
 - <input size="2" id="dmonth" name="dmonth" value="" maxlength="2" type="text">
 - <input size="2" id="dday" name="dday" value="" maxlength="2" type="text">
 <h3>Total Amount in Date Duration is: </h3>
```

I really appreciate for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that it's directly relevant to this problem, but what's your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amm` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_patient` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `opening_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rialamount` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Data**

```
INSERT INTO `amm` (`id`, `id_patient`, `opening_date`, `rialamount`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2015-11-07', 250000),
(2, 1, '2015-11-09', 25000),
(3, 1, '2015-11-09', 795864.15),
(4, 1, '2015-11-09', 12598755);
```

**SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT SUM(rialamount) as sum_result
FROM amm 
WHERE opening_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2015-11-07', '%Y-%c-%e') AND STR_TO_DATE('2015-11-09', '%Y-%c-%e')
GROUP BY id_patient;
```

**RESULT**

13669619.15

**PHP/HTML very simple implementation**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <h3>Total Amount is:</h3>
    <hr>
    <label for="fromdate">From Date:</label>
    <input size="4" id="fromdate" name="fromdate" value="" maxlength="4" type="text">
     - <input size="2" id="dmonth" name="dmonth" value="" maxlength="2" type="text">
     - <input size="2" id="dday" name="dday" value="" maxlength="2" type="text">

    <label for="todate">To Date:</label>
    <input size="4" id="todate" name="todate" value="" maxlength="4" type="text">
     - <input size="2" id="dmonth" name="tdmonth" value="" maxlength="2" type="text">
     - <input size="2" id="dday" name="tdday" value="" maxlength="2" type="text">
     <input type="submit" name="calculateFormSubmit" value="Get" />
     <h3>Total Amount in Date Duration is: </h3>
</form>

<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && array_key_exists("calculateFormSubmit", $_POST)) {
    $connectionData = [
        "server" => "",
        "user" => "",
        "pass" => "",
        "database" => ""
    ];



    $db = null;

    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $connectionData["server"] . ";dbname=" . $connectionData["database"], $connectionData["user"], $connectionData["pass"]);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $dateFrom = (int)$_POST["fromdate"] . "-" . (int)$_POST["dmonth"] . "-" . (int)$_POST["dday"];
    $dateTo = (int)$_POST["todate"] . "-" . (int)$_POST["tdmonth"] . "-" . (int)$_POST["tdday"];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT SUM(rialamount) as sum_result, id_patient
                          FROM amm 
                          WHERE opening_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(:date_from, '%Y-%c-%e') AND STR_TO_DATE(:date_to, '%Y-%c-%e')
                          GROUP BY id_patient;");

    $stmt->bindValue(":date_from", $dateFrom);
    $stmt->bindValue(":date_to", $dateTo);

    $stmt->execute();

    $userData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($userData != false) {
        foreach ($userData as $current) {
            echo "<b>" . $current["id_patient"] . "</b> - " . $current["sum_result"] . "<br />";
        }
    }

    if($db !== null) {
        $db = null;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: These table and columns are already created, as I mentioned I'm looking for PHP code, but you mentioned SQL QUERY... anyhow thanks

Comment: How do you know which result relates to which patient?

Comment: @AlexanderRichard If the tables were already created, Velko wouldn't have had to do that bit for you. They weren't, so Velko provided them.

Comment: I already have those functions to check patient, I need only PHP code to insert it into that page to show the result.

Comment: If you'll be able to give me a php code which can handle search based on date in my table column, it can be more enough, cause I can set it (To Date) Current date to show total amount.

Comment: Its pretty simple... you can make the improvements by your self. I think that this is what you want. For the next time give a better explication of your problem please.

Comment: I got error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied, maybe we don't need to add again sql user and password, cause All these functions are there. even I tried without checking again user and password of DB, but still error message is same.

Comment: Have you changed the values on `$connectionData = [
        "server" => "",
        "user" => "",
        "pass" => "",
        "database" => ""
    ];
` This is a connection error the username, password, server or database name is/are wrong
?

Comment: Actually I merged your php code into my existing code, Just I removed first lines about db username and etc, but still there's no result.

Comment: Cause no need to use again username and password, when I'm login into admin, and I'm in user profile, (( Patient ))

Comment: [Script Result](http://postimg.org/image/8vgro6m57/)
Have you change the table name in the sql query?

Comment: So, Now I entered username password database, there's no error message but there's no result too.

Comment: the table name which is included of rialamount and id_patient and opening_date, is ((problem_tbl))

Comment: Have you submitted the form ? The exact same form as I wrote ( I've made some changes ). And the html form as well the php script should be in the same file in the html file is not the same as the php file you have to change the value of action="". PS: Dont forget to change the table name in the sql quiery `SELECT SUM(rialamount) as sum_result, id_patient
                          FROM amm 
                          WHERE opening_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(:date_from, '%Y-%c-%e') AND STR_TO_DATE(:date_to, '%Y-%c-%e')
                          GROUP BY id_patient;`

Comment: Well if your tables name is problem_tbl change "amm" to "problem_tbl"

Comment: Yes done!! I forgot to change the "amm", now it's working.. but it won't get id_patient, it's calculation total column of rialamount, for example: If I'm in id_patient "1" profile, so total amount is correct, but when I'm in another patient profile like id_patient 2, it shows total amount, In the event that for id_patient 2 should be 0,  it shouldn't be like this. right?

Comment: I dont get it ... You want the total amount of 1 specific patient or a list with all patients with there respective amounts ?

Comment: If you want the amount for a specific patient you must add another condition 
`SELECT SUM(rialamount) as sum_result, id_patient
FROM amm 
WHERE opening_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(:date_from, '%Y-%c-%e') AND STR_TO_DATE(:date_to, '%Y-%c-%e')
 AND id_patient = '1'
GROUP BY id_patient;`
Now here you must change the value of id_patient

Comment: Your code is working well, it shows for all id_patient , How to change id_patient to current id_patient, because when it shows total amount, if we are in id_patient 3, it shows for patient 1, 2, 3 all patients ..

Comment: Do you have the id of the current user stored in some variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Air code here, but here goes:

```
Select id, sum(rialamount) from table where Id = $id and date between $start and $end group by id
```

You would pass the start and end parameters in your php form.